# date -d option usage in Shell Scripting

Tags: bash, shell, date, unix

```
date -d '($VAR) hours ago' +"%Y-%m-%d %H"
```

This gives me the wrong result. How do I pass in the variable in date -d option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables won't be expanded when put inside single quotes, use double quotes instead:

```
date -d "$VAR hours ago" +"%Y-%m-%d %H"
```